# Save rendered Jinja to variable

Tags: ansible

I'd like to split up some Jinja templating into multiple lines to keep lines under 120 characters, and register a variable for easy reuse. Is there a way to do something like the following? Is there a built-in (or community) module for this? If possible, I'd like to do it without using temporary files.

```
- jinja: "https://{{ username }}:{{ token }}@hosting.com/organization"
  vars:
    username: "{{ hashivault_secrets.value.data.USERNAME }}"
    token: "{{ hashivault_secrets.value.data.TOKEN }}"
  register: url
```

So the use/reuse could look something like

```
   - pip:
       name: my-internal-package
     env:
       PIP_EXTRA_INDEX_URL: "{{ url }}"
```

I'm currently using Ansible 2.9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just set a var directly:

```
  vars:
    url: https://{{ username }}:{{ token }}@hosting.com/organization
    username: "{{ hashivault_secrets.value.data.USERNAME }}"
    token: "{{ hashivault_secrets.value.data.TOKEN }}"
```

Or you can use `set_fact`:

```
- set_fact:
    url: https://{{ username }}:{{ token }}@hosting.com/organization
  vars:
    username: "{{ hashivault_secrets.value.data.USERNAME }}"
    token: "{{ hashivault_secrets.value.data.TOKEN }}"
```

The main practical difference (beyond setting variables not requiring an additional task) is that variables are evaluated at the time of use so the value of the first `url` might change over time if `hashivault_secrets` changes, while `set_fact` will result in a static value based on the evaluation of the template at the time the `set_fact` task runs. Both behaviours are useful, depending on the circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using [`set_fact`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/set_fact_module.html).

```
- set_fact:
    url: "https://{{ hashivault_secrets.value.data.USERNAME }}:{{ hashivault_secrets.value.data.TOKEN }}@hosting.com/organization"
```

Answer (score 0):

Vars can be defined as expressions referencing other vars. Allows splitting an expression to a reasonable size.

[The environment keyword](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_environment.html) can apply to all tasks of a play. This can reference vars defined anywhere.

[module_defaults](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_module_defaults.html) can also be used to provide a value to use when none is provided. This tends to be helpful for repetitive things like API creds in general. For pip module, gives an alternative of how to provide an  --extra-index-url  as the module provides a way to add arbitrary arguments.

group_vars/all/creds.yml  or wherever you want to define configuration vars.

```yaml
username: "{{ hashivault_secrets.value.data.USERNAME }}"
token: "{{ hashivault_secrets.value.data.TOKEN }}"
url: https://{{ username }}:{{ token }}@hosting.com/organization
env:
   PIP_EXTRA_INDEX_URL: "{{ url }}"
```

play.yml You did not provide a play, but this is a good place to use play scope keywords that will apply to all tasks. I'll make up a trivial play, adjust to what you are doing:

```yaml
- hosts: thingapp

  environment: "{{ env }}"

  module_defaults: 
    pip: 
      extra_args: "--extra-index-url {{ url }}"

  roles:
     - webserver
     - pythonapp
```

roles/pythonapp/tasks/main.yml

```yaml
   - pip:
       name: my-internal-package
```